# Magento sales_order_payment_pay observer does not fire

Tags: magento, observers

I'm trying to send information from my magento install to a dropshipper. This should obviously happen as soon as the payment is complete. As far as I can find Magento has the observer  which should be fired when payment is complete.

I have the following files, but the observer never seems to be fired:
app/etc/modules/SPB_Coreextended.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <SPB_Coreextended>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>          
        </SPB_Coreextended>
    </modules>
</config>
```

app/code/local/SPB/Coreextend/etc/config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <SPB_Coreextended>
            <version>0.2.0</version>
        </SPB_Coreextended>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <checkout>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <SPB_Coreextended before="Mage_Checkout">SPB_Coreextended_Checkout</SPB_Coreextended>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </checkout>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <models>
            <SPB_Coreextended>
                <class>SPB_Coreextended_Model</class>
            </SPB_Coreextended>
        </models>      
        <events>
            <sales_order_payment_pay>
                <observers>
                    <SPB_Coreextended>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>SPB_Coreextended/Observer</class>
                        <method>sendOrder</method>
                    </SPB_Coreextended>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_payment_pay>     
        </events>
     </global>
</config>
```

app/code/local/SPB/Coreextend/Model/Observer.php:

```
<?php
class SPB_Coreextended_Model_Observer 
{
    public function sendOrder($observer) {
        Mage::log("New order");
        $order = $observer->getInvoice()->getOrder(); // Mage_Sales_Model_Order
        Mage::log("New order");     
    }
}
?>
```

As you can see I also call another method from the config.xml, which does work. So I am pretty sure the problem is in my config.xml section for the observer. I just can't seem to find where it fails.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Silly addon question: could it be that the payment module I'm using does not use the function pay(), because it has no invoice status?

Comment: You could change your observer to sales_order_place_after and check the 'status' to see if it is invoiced (pay for)

Comment: Thanks. I implemented a second payment method that does offer the ability to create an invoice upon successful payment. When I use this payment provider it works. I will contact the other provider tomorrow to see if they can find a solution.